# Apache 2.4.6 AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned

Tags: apache, proxy

Working with apache 2.4.6, request sent to back and getting the below error when the response is received.

```
[proxy:debug] [pid 7:tid 140093959243520] proxy_util.c(2209): AH00942: HTTP: has acquired connection for (myportal.test.com)
[proxy:debug] [pid 7:tid 140093959243520] proxy_util.c(2262): [client 100.64.128.231:6945] AH00944: connecting http://myportal.test.com/test to myportal.test.com:80
[proxy:debug] [pid 7:tid 140093959243520] proxy_util.c(2442): [client 100.64.128.231:6945] AH00947: connected /test to myportal.test.com:80
[proxy:debug] [pid 7:tid 140093959243520] proxy_util.c(2818): AH02824: HTTP: connection established with 10.2.2.2:80 (myportal.test.com)
[proxy:debug] [pid 7:tid 140093959243520] proxy_util.c(2985): AH00962: HTTP: connection complete to 10.2.2.2:80 (myportal.test.com)10.1.1.1 - - [16/Jan/2021:19:09:09 +0000] "POST /test HTTP/1.0" 502 440 "-" "Java/1.8.0_212"
[proxy_http:error] [pid 7:tid 140093959243520] (20014)Internal error: [client 100.2.2.2:6945] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server myportal.test.com:80
[proxy_http:debug] [pid 7:tid 140093959243520] mod_proxy_http.c(1363): [client 100.2.2.2:6945] AH01105: NOT Closing connection to client although reading from backend server myportal.test.com:80 failed.
[proxy:error] [pid 7:tid 140093959243520] [client 100.2.2.2:6945] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /test
[proxy:debug] [pid 7:tid 140093959243520] proxy_util.c(2224): AH00943: HTTP: has released connection for (***************)
[proxy:debug] [pid 7:tid 140093959243520] proxy_util.c(2926): [remote 10.2.2.2:80] AH02642: proxy: connection shutdown
[headers:debug] [pid 7:tid 140093959243520] mod_headers.c(848): AH01503: headers: ap_headers_error_filter()
```

Have tried setting

SetEnv proxy-sendchunked 1
SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
RequestHeader unset Expect early

and also tried
ProxyPass /test http://myportal.test.com/test retry=2 acquire=3000 timeout=1000 Keepalive=On

nothing works, any suggestions?

Comment: have you found a solution? I'm struggling with the same thing

Comment: may I know if you found a solution yet? I am facing the same.